# How do i store many Values with one Key

Tags: java, store, key-value

I want to store 3 values in 1 key.
a Hashmap can only hold 1 key, 1 value, so that can not be used.
So what other ways do I have to get from the one key the Value A/B/C.

Key: String

Values: String/String/int

Comment: There are also (non-standard API) MultiMap implementations .. (not that I recommend here due to losing typing over a record, but something to keep in mind)

Comment: Im really new to HashMaps/Maps/Lists. So its pretty hard to understand   the solutions u discusse. i Try to understand and examaim the example. But i cant get the solution. so if there is a full working example. i Can learn from that and work from there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an object to hold your 3 values and then the new object is your value in the Key-value pair.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
class TripleValue {
    String A;
    String B;
    int C;

    public TripleValue(String a, String b, int c) {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}

public static void main() {
    Map<String, TripleValue> myMap = new HashMap<String, TripleValue>(); 
    myMap.put("SomeKey", new TripleValue("String1", "String2", 10));

}
```

Comment: e.g. `class Triple { String A; String B; int C; }`

Comment: If value list is dynamic, this solution may not be elegant.

Comment: @Nambari True but the OP lists the values as String/String/int

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question. how can i return the Values of the TripleValue? i tried iterator, but that didnt work

Code:

     for (Entry<String, TripleValue> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(entry.getValue());
  }

Comment: You need change it to this: `System.out.println(entry.getValue().A)`. getValue() merely returns the TripleValue object. You then need to access the difference properties on the TripleValue object.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now and i've learned something new :)

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to accept the answer if you think it was acceptable and useful :)

Answer (score 5):

One of the way may be use either ArrayList/Set as value for the key.

Example:

```
List myTempList = new ArrayList();
myTempList.add("Hi");
myTempList.add("Hello");
myTempList.add("How are you");

myMap.key("key", myTempList);
```

Another approach is, if you know that number of values for each key are always going to be same, then you can create a holder object and set values to that object and put it in map.

Comment: Using a heterogeneous `List` that will always contain 3 elements is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @oldrinb: Yes, my understanding is values are not predefined, if they are I agree with your statement. Updated answer with another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Map<Integer, List<yourObject>> m = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you will need to check if the list is present for a key. if so add to the list. Else create an ArrayList and add it

For example:

```
public add(String key, MyObj myobj){
    if (this.contains(key) ) { 
        this.get(key).add(myObj);
    }else {
        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        list.add(myObj);
        m.put(key, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `>` after the declared type of `m`. Also, as of Java 7, you can allow the compiler to infer the parameterized type of the created `HashMap` i.e. `new HashMap<>()`

Comment: yes good point @oldrib. I always forget the diamond operator!

Comment: @oldrinb what do you mean with: "infer the parameterized type of the created `HashMap`" - what would a code using this feature look like?

Comment: @yoshi look up the diamond operator. The answer has <> at the end of the declaration of HashMap which is using the diamond operator

Answer (score 0):

Java framework doesn't support [Multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), there is a way around it, see below.

```
Map<Object,ArrayList<Object>> multiMap = new HashMap<Object,ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Also take a look at this library [Guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)